# Sorting by the average of two fields in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, sorting

So I have a model with two fields: customer_rating and official_rating. I can obviously sort by one or the other. I'm curious: when doing a find, is there a clean way to sort by the average of both those fields?

Comment: what did you try so far? you should be able to at least get some basic find() up and running using "virtual fields"

Comment: Ah yes I can try a virtual field. I was curious as to whether something more like the SQL average operations were possible... without running a manual query.

Comment: they are very much possible - inside a virtual field.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping another field 'avg_rating' and populating it via an 'afterSave()' on the model.  It stays up-to-date, and you don't need to do excessive MySQL calculations constantly.

Should make your life a lot easier, as you can just deal with it like you would any other value at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Use [virtualFields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html)

```
$this->Model->virtualFields['sum_field'] = 'Model.field_1 + Model.field_2';
$this->Model->find('all', array(
    'order' => array(
        'Model.sum_field'
    )
));
```